# Missing data in Fabric for IOS "Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos"

Tags: ios, crash, stack-trace, google-fabric, dsym

I'm using Fabric.io to monitor and collect crash data for a IOS app.

I'm receiving now a lot of crash reports for this error "Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos" but when I check Fabric to analyze it I got the following report:

[image]

where the stack-trace of the crash is missing.
What should I do to receive the complete stack-trace?

App uses some libraries imported using CocoaPods.
I'm attaching here also a screenshot with linked libraries:
[image]

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I am facing the same issue that my app is crashing in iPhone XS having OS version 12.1.2 upon launch itself.

Comment: By now I have not found any solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that this report was sent because of missing "Privacy - Face ID Usage Description" (NSFaceIDUsageDescription) in Info.plist.
I have no idea why the report was not complete, but after adding this key my app has stopped crashing.